# I'm having issues with using an API

Tags: ruby, api, command-line-interface

I have the following code:

```
class EpisodeIndex::API

    def initialize
        @url = "https://www.officeapi.dev/api/episodes?limit=400"
    end

    def get_episode_data
        uri = URI.parse(@url)
        response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
        data = JSON.parse(response)
        data["data"].each do |episode|
            get_episode_title(episode["title"])
        end
    end

    def get_episode_title(title)
        uri = URI.parse(title)
        response = Net::HTTP.get(title)
        data = JSON.parse(response)
        binding.pry
    end

    EpisodeIndex::API.new.get_episode_data

end
```

and I'm getting this error in return.

```
`get_response': undefined method `hostname' for "Pilot":String (NoMethodError)
jocelynpeters@Jocelyns-Air office_cli %
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Be kind, please. I'm very new to programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data return by the API looks like this:

```
{
  "data":
    [
      {
        "_id":"5e94d646f733a1332868e1dc",
        "title":"Pilot",
        "description":"A documentary crew gives a firsthand introduction to the staff of the Scranton branch of the Dunder Mifflin Paper Company, managed by Michael Scott.",
        "writer": {
          "_id":"5e95242f9511994a07f9a319",
          "name":"Greg Daniels",
          "role":"Writer/Director",
          "__v":0
        },
        "director": {
          "_id":"5e9523649511994a07f9a313",
          "name":"Ken Kwapis",
           "role":"Director",
           "__v":0
        },
        "airDate":"2005-03-24T06:00:00.000Z",
        "__v":0
      },
      # ...
```

That means the result set already includes the title of each episode and it doesn't include any URL at which you could load further information (what you currently try in your `get_episode_title` method). Therefore you can simplify your code to:

```
module EpisodeIndex
  require "json"
  require "net/http"

  class API
    def initialize
      @url = "https://www.officeapi.dev/api/episodes?limit=400"
    end

    def titles
      uri = URI.parse(@url)
      response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
      
      data = JSON.parse(response)
      data["data"].map do |episode|
          episode["title"]
      end
    end
  end
end

EpisodeIndex::API.new.titles
#=> ["Pilot", "Diversity Day", "Health Care", "The Alliance", "Basketball", "Hot Girl", "The Dundies", "Sexual Harassment", "Office Olympics", "The Fire", "Halloween", "The Fight", "The Client", "Performance Review", "E-Mail Surveillance", "Christmas Party", "Booze Cruise", "The Injury", "The Secret", "The Carpet", "Boys and Girls", "Valentine's Day", "Dwight's Speech", "Take Your Daughter to Work Day", "Michael's Birthday", "Drug Testing", "Conflict Resolution", "Casino Night"]
```